# "for" loop over objects - can't get it working

Tags: java

I'm currently storing two objects of the type Target in an `ArrayList<Target>`. I'm then looping these  to the Target variable with the name `t`. `t` in turn is a parameter for the `fullScreen.find(t)` method.

This is working perfectly if I just use one target, no loop, no `ArrayList`. When I use them, it doesn't work.

Code:

```
public void loopButton() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        loopTargets();
        findButton();
        sleep();
    }
}

public void findButton() {
    try {
        ScreenRegion flix = fullScreen.find(t);
        ScreenRegion found = fullScreen.wait(t,5000);
        mouse.click(found.getCenter());
        System.out.println("Found");
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

public Target loopTargets() {
    for(int i = 0; i < targets.size(); i++) {
       t = targets.get(i); 
    }
    return t;
}
```

Comment: where is **For each Loop** ?

Comment: It's not clear what your `loopTargets` method is meant to do. It returns a single value, which happens to always be the last in the list - but the way you're calling it, you're ignoring the return value. Of course it also keeps the last one it finds in the `t` variable, which you haven't shown the declaration of. What do you expect that to *achieve*? Note that you're not doing anything with your `i` variable in `loopButton` - why are you looping at all?

Comment: You are having trouble understanding how loops and function calls works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably having trouble understanding how loops and function calls works.

To make it work, please restructure your code like this:

```
public void loopButton() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < targets.size(); i++) {
            Target t = targets.get(i); 
            findButton(t);
        }
        sleep();
    }
}

public void findButton(Target t) {
    try {
        ScreenRegion flix = fullScreen.find(t);
        ScreenRegion found = fullScreen.wait(t,5000);
        mouse.click(found.getCenter());
        System.out.println("Found");
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The problem with your code, is that your loopTarget methos always returns the last `Target` in the list:

```
public Target loopTargets() {
    for(int i = 0; i < targets.size(); i++) {
       // sets target in each iteration, but does not use it
       t = targets.get(i); 
    }
    return t; // return the last target set
}
```

Finally, the best option to iterate through your targets is using a foreach loop:

```
public void loopButton() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        for(Target t : targets) {
            findButton(t);
        }
        sleep();
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepted as soon as humanly possible, too low rep to upvote sadly

Answer (score 0):

`loopTargets` always return the last element from `targets`.

You want the code in `findButton` for each `target` in `targets`:

```
for(Target target : targets) {
    t = target;
    findButton();
}
```